# Spring Spark integration - java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: spring, apache-spark, spring-boot

I am using spring boot for my spark application and all dependencies are managed through spring and I am using Autowire to add dependency. My Function classes and Custom classes that are submitted to executors implements Serializable.

But when I run it and task is submitted to executors it throws exception: one spring class is not serilazable - `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.bikas.MyStarter(MyStarter:67) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:928) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:927) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:927) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:219) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:45) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.bikas.MyStarter.run(MyStarter:81) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, value: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@33a55bd8: startup date [Sun Aug 12 13:59:34 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy)
    - field (class: com.bikas.services.MyServiceImpl, name: applicationContext, type: interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
    - object (class com.bikas.services.MyServiceImpl, com.bikas.services.MyServiceImpl@1260c85e)
    - field (class: com.bikas.services.MyProcessor, name: myServiceImpl, type: interface com.bikas.services.MyService)
    - object (class com.bikas.services.MyProcessor, com.bikas.services.MyProcessor@2b551e7b)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1, name: f$12, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:342) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:928) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:927) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:927) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:219) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:45) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.bikas.MyStarter.run(MyStarter.java:81) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
```

Any help? or anyone else faced this problem?

Comment: add more stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

The functions and any classes containing the functions that run on the executors should not have any dependency on Spring Boot. See if you can find the reference by inspection, or maybe the serialisation stack trace will help you. Declaring the functions run on the executors as static methods in dedicated classes is a good way to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks this helps. So, that means I can not use anything related to spring? even spring jdbc? or any spring framework?

Comment: This may indicate you are trying to do something wrong, as the function is supposed to process a single element so probably shouldn't connect to a database for instance. However, any already instantiated objects that are referenced by the function and so will be copied across to the executor can be used as long as they and their references are Serializable, and any objects created in the function do not need to be Serializable as they are not copied across.

Comment: For each RDD partition, I need to get records from oracle to process, so I was trying to use the same existing code. So in my function logic there is a DB call to oracle and that uses spring jdbc, how can this be done in spark? or can I use plain JDBC?

Comment: You should be able to if you follow the rules I just mentioned. So as long as you create the Non-serializable objects in the function and don't transfer any such objects it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

will write a workaround I found.
You can have a spring component wrapper onto the component you want to call.
f.e.

```
@Component
public class ComponentIWantToUseWrapper {

    private static ComponentIWantToUse componentIWantToUse;

    public ComponentIWantToUseWrapper(ComponentIWantToUse component) {
        ComponentIWantToUseWrapper.componentIWantToUse = component;
    }

    public static ComponentIWantToUse getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

So that spring during component initialization will change the static variable of the wrapper. You can now use your component in spark lambdas like this  `ComponentIWantToUseWrapper.getComponent().someMethod()`.
Hope it'll help.